# aks: getting unauthorize error while trying to create load balancer

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I am getting below error while trying to create a load balancer in AKS,

> {"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client
> '85e23f21-xxxxxxxxxxx' with object id
> '85e23f21-xxxxxxxxxxx' does not have authorization to perform
> action 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/read' over scope
> '/subscriptions/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/resourceGroups/my-vnet/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/my-vnet/subnets/my-subnet'
> or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your
> credentials."}}

The client and object Id is same here and this is principalId for managed identity as my AKS cluster is managed identity enabled.

> ❯ az aks show -g my-rg -n my-aks --query "identity"
> {
> "principalId": "85e23f21-xxxxxxxxxxx",
> "tenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
> "type": "SystemAssigned",
> "userAssignedIdentities": null
> }

I have also enabled `azure RBAC` for my aks cluster

```
az aks update -g myResourceGroup -n myAKSCluster --enable-azure-rbac
```

What is missing here, how to give permission? Please help.

Comment: similar question asked here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51314726/azure-internal-load-balancer-with-azure-kubernetes-service-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because your VNet is not in the worker node Resource Group, hence the System assigned Identity can only managed ressources inside that Resource Group by default. You'll need to do a role assignement on the Principal ID of the cluster System Assigned Managed Identity to gave it permissions to managed ressource outside of that Resource Group. From the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity) :

> Note
>
> For creating and using your own VNet, static IP address, or attached
> Azure disk where the resources are outside of the worker node resource
> group, use the PrincipalID of the cluster System Assigned Managed
> Identity to perform a role assignment.

Comment: Thanks and appreciate @jJean-Philippe Bond for your reply. Could you please help me for my other question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68133452/aks-how-to-deploy-nginx-ingress-controller-only-to-user-node-pool

Comment: Suppose I've created AKS with bicep using `resource K 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters@2021-07-01' = { ... }` which principal needs this permission now? Is it `K.identity.principalId` or `K.properties.identityProfile.kubeletidentity.objectId` or something else?