# can I delete and re-create the AKS cluster with deleted cluster's API server address and IP address

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I have created a private aks cluster which creates a private DNS zone `xxx123dd-u0x0-123b-z123-xxxxxx1f1234.privatelink.eastus.azmk8s.io`.

The API server address after cluster creation is =  `myaks-aaaa.xxx123dd-u0x0-123b-z123-xxxxxx1f1234.privatelink.eastus.azmk8s.io` and the IP address for kube-apiserver is = `A.B.C.D`.

Now I want to delete the aks cluster (I am testing) and want to create it again with same IP address `A.B.C.D` and same API server address   `myaks-aaaa.xxx123dd-u0x0-123b-z123-xxxxxx1f1234.privatelink.eastus.azmk8s.io`. Is this possible?

I can see command to create a private AKS cluster with custom private DNS Zone,

but I am not sure what value I need to send for `--private-dns-zone` and `--fqdn-subdomain` plus do I need to pass IP address as well? Please suggest!

```
az aks create -n <private-cluster-name> -g <private-cluster-resource-group> 
--load-balancer-sku standard --enable-private-cluster 
 --enable-managed-identity --assign-identity <ResourceId> 
--private-dns-zone <custom private dns zone ResourceId> --fqdn-subdomain <subdomain-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible at you current setup. IP address by default is only valid for the lifespan of currently deployed instance. If you want to re-use IP address, deploy new [static IP address and then assign it to a new AKS cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip). This way you can redeploy AKS as many times you want using the same IP address.

Comment: Thanks, but article whatever you shared is about load balancer and it's NOT about AKS cluster creation